# Hovering trigger overlap CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with a double sub-menu li on my menu structure for refrence

```
Talent
 -Adult
  --Men
  --Woman
 -Children
  --Boys
  --Girls
```

If I hover on talent to open Adult and Children Its fine, but if I hover Adult the Men Sub-menu opens But if I try to scroll over it the Boys and girls submenu opens instead.

**Short: Hovering Adult Opens Sub Menu - Hover Submenu Opens Children Sub**

```css
#menu-item-35:hover .sub-menu #menu-item-43 {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu-item-35:hover .sub-menu #menu-item-40 {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu-item-43{
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-left:3px;
}

#menu-item-43 .sub-menu li{
  padding-top:3px;
}
#menu-item-40{
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
#menu-item-40 .sub-menu li{
  padding-top:3px;
}

#menu-item-43 .sub-menu{
  left:60%;
  bottom: 0%;
}
#menu-item-40 .sub-menu{
  left:60%;
  top:0%;
}
#menu-item-43:hover  #menu-item-45 {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events:all;
}

#menu-item-43:hover  #menu-item-44 { /*Male Sub */
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:all;
}

#menu-item-40:hover .sub-menu #menu-item-42 {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:all;
}

#menu-item-40:hover .sub-menu #menu-item-41 {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:all;
}

#menu-item-31 a, #menu-item-28 a{
  padding:5px!important;
}

#menu-item-40 .sub-menu{
  padding-left:10px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
#menu-item-43 .sub-menu{
  padding-left:10px;
  pointer-events:none;

}

#menu-item-35:hover{
  border: none!important;
}

#menu-item-35 *{
  padding-bottom: 1px!important;
}

#menu-item-35{
  position: relative;
}

#menu-item-35 .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu-item-39 active ">
    <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/" aria-current="page">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38">    <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/about-main/">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-35">
    <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/">TALENT</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-43">
          <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Aadult">Adults</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45">
              <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Amale">Male</a>               </li>
            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44">
              <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Afemale">Female</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-40">
      <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Achild">Kids</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-42">       <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Aboy">Boys</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41">       <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Agirl">Girls</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36">
    <a href="https://kellyjeancasting.com/contact-main/">CONTACT</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

```
item-35 = Talent
item-43 = Adults
  item-45/44 = Adult-sub
item-40 = Kids
  item-42/41 = Kids-sub
```

You are more than welcome to go onto the site and see the interaction: [Sitelink](https://kellyjeancasting.com) Hover Talent and try to hover over Men or Woman

Comment: _“Hover Talent and try to hover over Men or Woman”_ - I did, and then I clicked on “Men”, and it took me to https://kellyjeancasting.com/talent-main/?vp_filter=category%3Amale Tested in a current Chromium-based browser.

Comment: Interesting so if u hover talent then hover adults u can hover over to men without it changing to the child submenu?

Comment: Works when the upper half of “Adults” is hovered, not on the lower half. Add `outline: 1px solid red` for `.menu li a`, then you can see how the links are actually bigger than their containing `li`, and therefor partially overlap.

Comment: The links break out of the LI box with their top and bottom padding, because they are inline elements. Add `display:block` for the links, and then correct the paddings to how much spacing you actually want.

Comment: Thanks wanna stash that in a answer so I can accept it for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works when the upper half of “Adults” is hovered, not on the lower half. Add `outline: 1px solid red` for `.menu li a`, then you can see how the links are actually bigger than their containing `li`, and therefor partially overlap.

The links break out of the LI box with their top and bottom padding, because they are inline elements. Add `display:block` for the links, and then correct the paddings to how much spacing you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

I have change your CSS

```
ul{
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li{
  position:relative;
  
}
ul li > ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  width:60px;
display:none;  
}
ul li:hover > ul{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/a4uL73sz/5/